# Cannot get sf::Text attribute in a list iterator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, sfml

I am working on a small game in C++ using sfml. When you press the TAB button a small menu with four buttons appears on the right of the screen. I created a `class Button` and in the class I have an `sf::Text` attribute. Here is the code I use to draw the menu.

```
void DrawRightSideMenu(RenderWindow &win)
{
    window.draw(rectInGameMenu);
    for (list<Button>::iterator currentButton = rightSideMenuButtons.begin(); currentButton != rightSideMenuButtons.end(); currentButton++)
    {
        win.draw(*currentButton);
        Text buttonTextToDraw = currentButton->GetButtonText(); //Crash here
        win.draw(buttonTextToDraw);
    }
}
```

Before doing this code, all the buttons are created in another function. `rectInGameMenu` is just a rectangle and it works fine. `win.draw(*currentButton);` works well but there is no text in the button wich is to be expected. So the program crashes when I use the `GetButtonText()`. This so I can draw text in the button. I get an error that says that it cannot read that emplacement in the memory (Violation d'accès lors de la lecture de l'emplacement 0x550030BD). Sorry for the French, I use Visual Studio in French. I really don't know what I can do to solve this problem. I did a bit of researched but I could not find anyone with the same problem... I've had this problem for a few days now and I really don't know what I can do to solve it. If there is a better way of doing this, please feel free to tell me.

EDIT:

Here is the code where I create my buttons:

```
Button aButton;
aButton = Button(10, "Ressources/Fonts/font.ttf");
aButton.SetButtonText("Button Text");
aButton.setSize(Vector2f(246, 60));
aButton.setFillColor(Color(22, 235, 65));
aButton.setPosition(773, 120);
aButton.GetButtonText().setPosition(240, 30);
rightSideMenuButtons.push_back(aButton);
```

This is in a void function that is called when the game window is created. Now here are my methods that I use in my `class Button`:

```
Button::Button(int inFontSize, string inFontButton)
{
    fontSize = inFontSize;
    fontButton.loadFromFile(inFontButton);
}

void Button::SetButtonText(string inButtonText)
{
    buttonText.setString(inButtonText);
    buttonText.setFont(fontButton);
    buttonText.setCharacterSize(fontSize);
    buttonText.setColor(Color(255, 255, 255));
}
```

Those are the methods being used by the function. `buttonText` is a `Text` attribute. `fontButton` is a `Font` attribute. Hope this helps you guys a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Check these:

- Make sure your text font laoded correctly
- Give a color to your text
- Give it a string before rendering

Here's a function from my engine that adds text to the game:

```
void Actor::addRenderedElement(sf::Text * txt, const char * font_name, const char* text, sf::Color color)
{
    if (checkGameData()) {
        sf::Font* _font = gamedata->getFont(font_name);
        if (_font != nullptr) {
            txt->setFont(*_font);
            txt->setString(text);
            txt->setColor(color);
            renderedShapes.push_back(txt);
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Invalid font name " << font_name << " for " << name << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Et installe l'anglais sur visual ;)

EDIT:
From your edited code:
Since Button seems to also be a shape, are you sure that you gave it a texture?
And how did you make sure that your font is loaded correctly, i don't see any error handling
Can i see the `GetButtonText()` function?
Why not overload the `draw()` function in your button to also draw the text?
Where do you add the new button to your `rightSideMenuButtons` Array?

And is this working?

```
win.draw(currentButton->GetButtonText());
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it when I get back home tonight. And yes, I will probably switch to the English version hahahaha!

Comment: I made sure that my font is loaded correctly, the text has a color and that it has string but still no good. With a bit more research I found out this is most likely a problem with pointers. I will either keep looking for a solution or just change my way of doing things.

Comment: I'll need a bit more of your code to figure out what's wrong